# how to hide a div after a few seconds using jQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show a div for 5 seconds when the web page is loaded and then make it disappear. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#mask').hide();
}, 5000);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mask">
<h2>This div will fade out </h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code doesn't work, however if I delete the single line that calls jQuery mobile javascript

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

it works perfectly. 
Any idea on how I can make it work having both jQuery and jQuery mobile in the `<head>` section?

Comment: Can you add code that works for you?

Comment: Post the exact code that isn't working, not just the code that is. JQuery Mobile isn't the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/5vgxexbt/

Answer (score 0):

As jQuery initialises lots of event listeners wrap up your code on an event listener like:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#hide').hide();
    }, 5000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wcuxS/1457/

Answer (score 0):

Try including the div in your first page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <div id="mask">           
            <h2>This div will fade out </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then add your script within the pagecreate event:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#mask').hide(800);
    }, 5000);
});
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5vgxexbt/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

You need to work with the Jquery Mobile api. Embed you timeout function within the $(document).on('pageinit') event callback. Also I am not sure if its called 'pageinit' but there is a Jquery Mobile event that behaves like $(document).on('ready'). Do some research on the JQM api